# Adobe Test and Target mbox.js giving an error

Tags: adobe, test-and-target

I am getting an error and not able to find any solution on adobe forum. The error says "Uncaught TypeError: TNT.a.Bb is not a function"
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uOYx.png)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?